# Conditional replace a list element in rstudio

Tags: vector, indexing, replace, match, rstudio

Hello I have a dataframe like the below:

```
 path.vec                           source.vec                        
1 apple                             Tuesday                        
2 lemon                             Monday                         
3 orange                            Wednesday                          
4c("apple", "lemon", "grape")       c("Friday", "Monday", "Sunday")     
5c("cheery", "lemon", "grape")      c("Saturday", "Monday", "Sunday")      
6c("apple", "lemon", "apple")       c("Thursday", "Monday", "Sunday")
```

just 2 variables: path.vec and source.vec. Both are collecting 2 different shadows of the same data

[image]

I would like simply to swap elements between lists with same index when a condition is met.

Ratio should be:

if df$path.vec contains "apple" swap with df$source.vec same index element

I have tried the below:

```
df$path.vec <- ifelse(grepl("apple", df$path.vec), df$source.vec, df$path.vec)
```

but this is changing all the elements, when there is at least one element =="apple", while I want to change just the element "apple". I'm thinking that probably i need to find indexes first and after to base my swap on the index?
I have tried

```
ind  <- which(df$path.vec %in% c("apple"))
```

but in my real data set this is an error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, path.index, value = 1:6) : 
 replacement has 6 rows, data has 33422
```

because it's indexing just when apple is the only element of the list.

I have also tried

```
df$path.index <- match("apple", df$path.vec)
```

but this results just in 1 every single row of my dataframe.

Is this one the best way to approach this?

Eventually I would like to obtain another column like the below:

```
path.final                                               
1 Tuesday                                                          
2 lemon                                                      
3 orange                                                
4c("Friday", "lemon", "grape")        
5c("cheery", "lemon", "grape")     
6c("Thursday", "lemon", "Sunday")
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this like the following:

Once the lists have names:

```
names(path.vec) <- c(1:6)

path.final <- lapply(1:length(path.vec), function(x) {
res <- path.vec[[x]]
pos <- grep("apple", res, fixed = T)
if(length(pos) > 0) res[pos]  <- source.vec[[x]][pos]
res
})
```